# Ionic 4 routing not working the url changes but view doesnt appear

Tags: routes, ionic4

I am developping an Ionic 4 application,  I have two page authentication and registration, I added my route in "app-routing.module", I set my Authentication component as a root component , so when I click on a button on the view the route changes and the registration view doesnt appear:

The App-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthenticationComponent },
  { path: 'registerFirst', component: RegistrationComponent},
];
  ...
```

This is the button inside the Authentication view

```
<ion-button expand="full" color="medium" [routerLink]="['/registerFirst']">CREATE AN 
 ACCOUNT</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your routing like this:

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    loadChildren: 'yourpath/registration.module#RegistrationPageModule'
  },
  ...
```

And you must add this code to `registration.module.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistrationPage
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
 .....
})
```

And I hope it works outright

Comment: It doesn't, I have the same exact problem and this is how the routes are set up by default by the Ionic CLI and it's still not working.

Comment: I ended up posting a separate answer to this question

Comment: Do i need to have module for every page i create ?

Comment: No, it is optional

Answer (score 2):

I had this same exact issues and the solution turned out to be kinda unexpected:

I commented out this line from global.scss: `@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";`, uncommenting it fixed the rendering issue.

The reason why a lot of people have this issue is because migrating from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 is kinda confusing and commenting out stuff just to add them back in one by one is a good approach to understand what's going on, unfortunately, if you end up commenting the wrong lines this kind of issues might arise.